# Unable to copy files from remote directory from IIS service using powershell script

Tags: powershell, iis

I have a few files that need to be copied from a Server A to Server B. There is an IIS service running on Server B which calls a local powershell script to do the needful.

When the powershell script is executed from the command line, it works as expected and also works when executed from within IISExpress. But when called from the service hosted on IIS, there is no error reported, but no files get copied either.

The powershell script basically calls `Copy-Item -Path \\Server A\<some path> -Destination c:\<some path>`

Thank You!

Comment: Does the Service account in IIS have access to the source and destination folders? Check the Identity of the App Pool your service is running under.  Open a powershell session as that Identity and try to run your Copy-Item script to see if there are any permission errors.

Comment: @RichMoss will I have to create a network user with rights to both servers then?

Comment: Yes, it seems likely that the service identity would be local to the server, unless you explicitly set the identity to be a domain account. This is speculative - you can only know for sure what's happening by running the script as the service account.

Comment: @RichMoss, yes, that did work. Though managing passwords is going to be a hassle Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS by default runs as a local service account that doesn't have network permission. You probably couldn't see an error message because the Powershell script wasn't echoing it's output to the HTTP response.

To fix this you can create a new Application Pool in IIS and set the identity by entering network credentials in the AppPool's Advanced Settings -> Identity. 
Then make your Service run in that AppPool by right-clicking on the Virtual Directory and selecting "Add Application". A dialog box will appear where you can select the new AppPool.

Notes:

- The credentials you enter in the AppPool are not updated when the network password changes, so you should use a domain account with a password that doesn't expire.
- You should not use your own account because it could get locked out if your password changes and your service is invoked.
- The password is readable by any administrator on the IIS server.